# SerialPort Read Doesn't Work in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

i am develop C# windows app.it's read weight from weigh bridge machine to serial port.but,my code doesn't work.i am trying many examples download from internet doesn't work.my code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace SerialPortTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String a = "";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }
        timer1.Start();
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            a = a + serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (a.Length != 0)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(a);
                a = "";
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i am wrong in my code can any one help me any working code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: The code isn't thread-safe. You will miss char very very occasionally.

Comment: @HenkHolterman how to read serial port data with thread safe?

Comment: Like you write any other thread-safe code: with great care for details and a thorough understanding of the issues.

Comment: Could you provide any information on how the machine transmits data through the serial port? It's very hard to help you without knowing anything about how the PC side should process the data it gets.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't register the serialPort1_DataReceived for serialPort1.

```
serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
```

Comment: i am receive continuously like ?x???????x?x?x??x???x??x???x???x?.but,i want receive number format?

Comment: @Dinesh then why do you use "ReadExisting" which returns string?

Comment: it's not return string how do i convert number format from serial port data?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to extract the binary data from the stream instead of reading the data as a string?

Here's an example of some code that could be inside the DataReceived event handler...

```
int nb = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
if (nb > 0) 
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[nb];
  serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, nb);

  // Depending on the structure of the binary data ...
  int number1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
  int number2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 4);
  // etc.
}
```