# Using serial (RS232) scales in WCF in VB

Tags: vb.net, wcf, serial-port

At work I have to get some scales to talk to the computer system, this itself is not particularly difficult as I already have a working utility. the problem is that our control system uses WCF and when I was brought on I had no experience working with VB. I have managed to get the WCF service to send data through the com port but am struggling with receiving. does anyone else have any advice or links that may help? I feel that I may have spent too long trying to get this work as I have been trying since friday...

Comment: Does the utility you say is working, work in both directions ok? i.e. sending and receiving?

Comment: Yes, everything seems to work other than the data received event, I know that the scales send afterwards because I simulated them as well as tested them on the production machine.

Comment: Can you update your question with the snippet of code which is registering the data received event and reading from the serial port...

Comment: And what working utility are you using to communicate with the scales?

Comment: I pretty much copied the MSDN here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)

Comment: That MSDN example - which calls serialPort.ReadExisting() - is only good for string/ASCII format data ... if its in some sort of binary encoding, then you'd need to extract the data using something like this method I posted on an answer for another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12178880/507950

Comment: The received data reads as text in PuTTY, it has a four digit number followed by a space and then "KG" so as far as I know it is ASCII...